# Accordions clicked with puppeteer not revealing tables after being clicked

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

I've been trying to open a webpage that has a set of accordions which are to be clicked before being scraped with puppeteer. When any of the accordions are clicked, they're supposed to reveal a table. I was able to click one accordion and get html with the table opened returned but when I try looping through all accordions and clicking each of them, they usually all get clicked (not all times) but only one table opens. Here's the code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage()
page.setDefaultTimeout(0)
await page.goto(url)

const accordions = await page.$$("div.accordion__item.j-tabPane")
accordions.forEach(async(tab, i) => {
const button = await page.$$(`body > div.container.container--body > div.region.region--primary > div 
> div > mw-hybrid > div:nth-child(${i + 1})`)
await button[0].click()
await page.waitForSelector("body > div.container.container--body > div.region.region--primary > div > 
div > mw-hybrid > div:nth-child(${i + 1}) > div.accordion__body.j-tabBody > div > div > div > table")
})
const html = await page.content()
```

The `waitForSelector` is only one way i've tried slowing down the process to make sure everything loaded properly. I've tried using the `{waitUntil: "networkidle"}` option and `{waitUntil: "load"}` to ensure page was fully loaded before clicking around and even `page.waitForTimeout(1000)` after every click, none solved the problem. Most of the accordions appear to have been clicked but only one reveals a table. I have also tried using `page.evaluate()` to trigger a click on the accordions, didn't even appear to do anything.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log("clicking");
        let accordions = document.querySelectorAll("div.accordion__item.j-tabPane")
        accordions.forEach(accordion => {
            accordion.click()
        })
    })
```

I see the log but no clicking even happens here.

Comment: This is the link to the webpage: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/nok?type=stock&page=options. Sorry for the late reply, didn't see comment early

Comment: And I've tried clicking the buttons as well as the accordions directly. In both cases, they all get clicked but only one table opens